# matplotlib plot_dates break the line when yaxis integer change length

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have a data:number matching lists.
I change the length of each list to 32~.
than I plot:

```
    list_of_datetimes = [s for (i, s) in enumerate(list_of_datetimes) if (i % (len(list_of_datetimes) >> 5)) == 0]
    y_axis = [s for (i, s) in enumerate(y_axis) if (i % (len(y_axis) >> 5)) == 0]

    dates = mdates.datestr2num(list_of_datetimes)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y'))
    #plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
    plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    plt.plot_date(dates, y_axis, linestyle='solid', marker='None')
```

And I don't understand why chart is breaking:
[chart_breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbQnw.png)

Answer (score 2):

This is because your y axis is being sorted in alphabetical order, rather than from smallest to largest.

Change the type of what gets plotted on your y axis to `float` or `int` and it should work:

```
y_axis = [float(s) for (i, s) in enumerate(y_axis) if (i % (len(y_axis) >> 5)) == 0]
```

Comment: WORKS ! Thanks. (I can't believe I found nothing about it online)